# Difference between firebase/token-generator and firebase/php-jwt

Tags: javascript, php, rest, authentication, firebase

I have migration problems after the major firebase upgrade:

**I want to access my firebase database in two different ways.** **REST and Web (Javascript)**. **Both work fine, but in different ways**:

1. Javascript Authentication with a custom **firebase/php-jwt** token works fine

   - PHP: Generating a token with **firebase/php-jwt** and a Google Service Account
   - Javascript: firebase web auth with signInWithCustomToken()

AND

2. REST Authentication with **firebase/token-generator** works fine

   - PHP: Generating a token with **firebase/token-generator** and the Firebase Secret
   - REST: request with https://xxx.firebaseio.com/path.json?auth=$token

In firebase 2.x.x i used firebase/token-generator for both situations. Do i have to use both libraries in the new (3.x) firebase or **is there a way to get one of the libraries working for both use-cases**?

Comment: why are you using the 2 libraries? what can you do on the first PHP that you cannot on the second?